# Insert Data using JDBC to a MySQL database through a method

Tags: forms, servlets, jdbc

I have a form and I want to send the data to a database. How can I pass the request data through the method parameters and send it to the Database?

```
int status = InsertCustomer(fName, mName, lName , iage, issn, city, state, country);
```

//Method
 // This method should return an int that the executeUpdate       // methods returns. Note: the driver name and the URL are       // already available in the init() method.

```
  private int InsertCustomer(String firstName, String midName, String lastName, int age, int ssn, String city, String state, String country) {

    // JDBC logic


    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL);
        java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();


        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Customer(firstName, midName, lastName, age, ssn, city, state, country)" + 
                   "VALUES ('?', '?', '?', ?, ?, '?', '?', '?')";


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I'm a lil bit lost, a little would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use a simple (i.e. not prepared statement), and you can't pass any parameter:

```
String sql = "insert into sometable (a, b, c) values (7, 8, 9)";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
return st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Or (and in your case, that's what you should do), you use a prepared statament and pass parameters:

```
String sql = "insert into sometable (a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setInt(1, 7);
st.setInt(2, 8);
st.setInt(3, 9);
return st.executeUpdate();
```

In your code, you're using a simple statement and try to execute a SQL query which needs parameters. That's not possible. You need a prepared statement to do that.

More information in [the JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Thank You, let me give it a try

Comment: Question: is the a, b, c database columns?

Comment: Just a note: please respect the Java naming conventions: methods start with a lower-case letter; variables are not prefixed with m, f, l, i or any other letter.

Comment: Yes, a, b and c are columns of the table sometable in the example.